# Wie viele Vokale gibt es im Deutschen?

Tags: phonetics, vowel

**Wie viele verschiedene Vokale lassen sich im gesprochenen Deutsch voneinander unterscheiden?**

---

Ich habe nach der Anzahl der Vokale im gesprochenen Deutsch im Internet gesucht, und habe eine [Liste](http://www.eupedia.com/linguistics/number_of_phonemes_in_european_languages.shtml) gefunden, in der die Anzahlen der Phoneme von europäischen Sprachen miteinander verglichen werden. In dieser Liste steht, dass Deutsch 17 Vokale (Monophthonge) und drei Diphthonge hat, sowie 25 Konsonanten, die mich im Moment aber weniger interessieren.

Wikipedia listet in seinem [Artikel über Vokale](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokal) aber nur 15 Vokale (Monophthonge) auf, wenn man den Unterschied zwischen betont und unbetont, sowie zwischen kurz und lang ignoriert. Unterscheidet man aber zwischen kurzen und langen Vokalen (z.B. Stall - Stahl), dann hat Deutsch laut Wikipedia 23 Vokale. Geht man einen Schritt weiter, und unterscheidet zusätzlich zwischen betonten und unbetonten Vokalen, dann kommt man (nach derselben Quelle) auf diese 30 verschiedenen Vokale:

1. [ˈiː] **I**gel
2. [i] d**i**rekt
3. [ˈɪ] fr**i**sch
4. [ɪ] Ärzt**i**n
5. [ˈeː] Schn**ee**
6. [e] l**e**bendig
7. [ə] Blum**e**
8. [ˈɛː] M**ä**dchen
9. [ˈɛ] n**e**tt
10. [ɛ] v**e**rlieren (1)
11. [ˈaː] V**a**ter
12. [ˈa] K**a**tze
13. [a] d**a**heim
14. [ɐ] Brud**er**
15. [ˈoː] T**o**n
16. [o] R**o**sine
17. [ˈɔ] S**o**nne
18. [ɔ] Kosm**o**s (2)
19. [ˈuː] g**u**t
20. [ˈu] k**u**lant
21. [ˈʊ] M**u**nd
22. [ʊ] Neig**u**ng
23. [ˈyː] m**ü**de
24. [ˈy] B**ü**ro
25. [ˈʏ] h**ü**bsch
26. [ʏ] Abk**ü**rzung
27. [ˈøː] K**ö**nig
28. [ˈø] **Ö**konomie
29. [ˈœ] l**ö**schen
30. [œ] Essl**ö**ffel

Obwohl diese Liste sehr lang ist, bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob sie alle Vokale des Standard-Deutschen enthält.

<sub>(1) Ich suche ein besseres Beispiel für das kurze unbetonte [ɛ] (kurzer unbetonter ungerundeter halboffener Vorderzungenvokal), denn in »verlieren« ist dieser Vokal Teil eines Diphthongs ([ɛɐ̯] in [fɛɐ̯ˈliːʀən]). Schön wäre ein Wort, in dem dieser Vokal als Monophthong auftritt.</sub>

<sub>(2) Ich suche ein besseres Beispiel für das kurze unbetonte [ɔ] (kurzer unbetonter gerundeter halboffener Hinterzungenvokal), denn »Kosmos« enthält in der ersten Silbe auch eine betonte Version desselben Vokals, wodurch es zu Verwechslungen kommen kann.</sub>

<sub>Hinweis zur Lautschrift: Es gibt offenbar kein Lautschriftzeichen, mit denen die Betonung oder Nicht-Betonung von Vokalen gekennzeichnet werden kann. Es gibt aber ein Zeichen, dass in einem mehrsilbigen Wort den Beginn einer betonten Silbe kennzeichnet, es ist das Zeichen »ˈ«. Ich verwende es hier, um die Betonung des nachfolgenden Vokals anzuzeigen. Fehlt dieses Betonungszeichen in der Liste, dann ist ausdrücklich ein unbetonter Vokal gemeint. Das Längenzeichen »ː« hinter einem Vokal kennzeichnet wie üblich einen langen Vokal. Fehlt das Längenzeichen in der Liste, dann ist ausdrücklich ein kurzer Vokal gemeint.</sub>

Ich habe nun aber das Problem, bei einigen Vokal-Paaren keinen Unterschied wahrzunehmen. So hören sich für mich z.B. das [i] in »d**i**rekt« und das [ɪ] in »Ärzt**i**n« gleich an. Ähnlich geht es mir bei dem Paar [ˈeː] - [ˈɛː]. Letzteres liegt aber daran, dass ich als Österreicher nicht gewohnt bin, den Laut [ˈɛː] zu verwenden, denn in Österreich werden [ˈɛː] und [ˈɛ] generell durch [ˈeː] und [ˈe] ersetzt.

Für das Vokalpaar [ˈeː] - [ˈɛː] gibt es aber Wortpaare, die belegen sollen, dass es sich hier um unterschiedliche Laute handelt:

- Seele - Säle ([ˈzeːlə] -  [ˈzɛːlə])
- Beeren - Bären ([ˈbeːʀən] -  [ˈbɛːʀən])

In Österreich wird zwar das Wort »Säle« so ausgesprochen wie »Seele« im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum, und »Bären« wie »Beeren«, aber ich habe gelernt, dass man anderswo durchaus einen klar wahrnehmbaren Unterschied macht. Daher kann ich auch nachvollziehen, dass [ˈeː] und [ˈɛː] zwei verschiedene Laute sind.

Im Fall des Paares [i] - [ɪ] kann ich aber derzeit keine Begründung dafür finden, das als zwei verschiedene Vokale aufzufassen. Für mich ist das derselbe Laut. Dasselbe nehme ich bei vielen anderen Paaren ebenfalls wahr. Für mich klingen [o] und [ɔ] gleich, ebenso [ˈy] und [ˈʏ] oder auch [ˈø] und [ˈœ].

Mich interessiert nun, wieviele verschiedene Vokale die deutsche Sprache hat, bzw. welche Laute-Paare zwar unterschiedlich klingen, aber vertauscht werden dürfen, ohne dass das zu einer veränderten Bedeutung des Wortes führt.

Bei der Beantwortung dieser Frage können vermutlich auch Minimalpaare helfen, die Gegenstand einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/34784/1487) sind.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass man Dialekte ausnehmen kann. Jemand, der Dialekt spricht, wird automatisch auch seine Vokale, die er mitbringt, verwenden. Und in der Tagesschau habe ich durchaus auch schon die klassisch sächsische Aussprache von "Erzgebirge" (Im "E" sind mindestens drei Vokale drin ;) gehört.

Comment: @tofro: Wenn etwas in der Tagesschau gesendet wird, und nicht gerade ein Versprecher ist, ist es Standarddeutsch und steht somit im Fokus meiner Frage. Wenn es am Wirtshaustisch gesagt wird, während es undenkbar ist, da genau so in der Tagesschau zu sagen, dann liegt es nicht im Fokus meiner Frage. Ds wäre zwar auch sehr interessant, würde aber ob der Vielzahl verschiedener Dialekte den Umfang der Frage sprengen.

Comment: @tofro: (Fortsetzung) Aus einem ähnlichen Grund habe ich Diphthonge (und damit implizit auch Tri- und Multiphthonge) ausgeschlossen. Wikipedia nennt 4 Standard-Diphthonge (zu finden in *Haus, Leim, Heu, pfui*) und 8 Diphthonge, die durch die Aussprache des Buchstaben R als Schwa am Silbenende entstehen (z.B. in *Bier, Uhr, Bär* usw.). Das halte ich zwar auch für sehr interessant, aber ich halte es auch für zu viel um es auch noch mitzubehandeln.

Comment: Was ich sagen wollte, ist, dass man die *Fähigkeit*, bestimmte Laute (also auch Vokale) zu erzeugen, beim kindlichen *Spracherwerb* mit erwirbt und "hochdeutsche Laute" mit dem, was man gelernt hat, annähert. Selbst wenn man später "nur hochdeutsch" spricht, ist es sehr schwierig, diese Fähigkeit dabei nicht zu verwenden (oder andersrum, siehe alle "Chinesenwitze", die sich um das "R" drehen). Und: Die meisten, die "deutsch" lernen, tun das in irgendeinem Dialekt, werden also irgendeine "Färbung" annehmen.

Comment: @tofro: Da gebe ich dir zu 100% recht. Aber um genau den Einfluss dieser unterschiedlichen Färbungen auszuschließen, weil sie kein Einfluss auf die Bedeutung von Wörtern haben, möchte ich mich auf jenes Deutsch konzentrieren, das von ausgebildeten Berufssprechern produziert wird.

Comment: Erstmal ein paar Ergänzungsvorschläge, die aber soweit ich sehe nicht wirklich weiterhelfen: _stehl’, stell, steil; würd’, wurd’; Hammel; Kaste; Ma(a)re, Mure, Moore, Maure; toller, Taler; voll, fehl’, fühl, fahl, faul, feil; birg, barg, borg/Borg; bind; pellen, Pillen, pulen, peilen; lesen; Basse, Bässe, büße; steck, stak, Stock, Steg, Stick, stieg, steig_

Comment: Ist das vielleicht eine Community-Wiki-Frage, da mehrere Antworten gesucht werden?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich würde erstmal für ein Aufteilen in mehrere Fragen plädieren. Für die dritte Frage bietet sich dann eventuell eine Community-Wiki-Antwort an.

Comment: @Hubert Wie definierst du "unterscheiden"? An Phonemen gibts standardsprachlich nicht wirklich was außer [denen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache#Monophthonge); und Betontheit zu unterscheiden, macht bei einzelnen Lauten keinen Sinn, weil sie sich immer auf ein gesamtes Wort bezieht und nur auf Vokalqualität _auswirkt_.

Comment: Länge ist halt schwierig, weil sie supresegmental ist, und phonologisch so stark mit Gespanntheit korrelliert, aber in der Realisierung "schwinden" kann (zB. [ø], oder dein [i]/[ɪ]). Man ist sich, glaube ich, trotzdem ziemlich einig, dass (fast immer) jeweils nur ein gespanntes und "langes" und ein ungespanntes und "kurzes" Phonem zugrunde liegen. TL/DR: suchst du jetzt Phoneme (weil Minimalpaare?), oder alle Variationen von deren Realisierung in der Standardsprache?

Comment: @phg: Ich suche Vokal-Phoneme. Also alle klingenden Laute (Vokale), die sich mit Hilfe von Minimalpaaren von anderen Vokalen unterscheiden lassen. Auf ein Beispiel heruntergebrochen: Gibt es ein [i]/[ɪ]-Minimalpaar, oder sind [i] und [ɪ] Allophone desselben Phonems? Dieselbe Frage stelle ich für alle 435 Paare, die man aus den 30 Vokalen bilden kann, die laut Wikipedia in deutschen Wörtern vorkommen. Zusatzfrage: Gibt es (deutsche) Vokale, die in dieser Liste fehlen, sich aber trotzdem mit Hilfe von Minimalpaaren von den anderen abgrenzen lassen?

Comment: @phg: Ich weiß, du hast auf die Liste der Monophthonge verlinkt, aber direkt darunter steht eine Liste von Diphthongen, und diese Liste ist definitiv unvollständig. Der Diphthong, der in »*pfui*« vorkommt, ist nicht der Liste enthalten.

Comment: @phg: Und in der Liste der Monophthonge fehlt [ɐ] (Letzer Vokal in »erst**er**«, »jed**er**«, usw.) Daher habe ich grundlegende Zweifel an diesen Wikipedia-Listen, vor allem weil es in Wikipedia mehrere solche Listen gibt, die jedoch einander widersprechen.

Comment: Was ist l**e**bendig? Ich habe immer gedacht, das hieße leb**e**ndig?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Die fette Hervorhebung bedeutet nicht, dass dieser Vokal betont ist (so verstehe ich jedenfalls deine Frage). Wie du siehst, steht in meiner Liste zu jedem Vokal ein Beispielwort. Im Fall des unbetonten Vokals [e] ist das das Wort »lebendig«. Nun enthält dieses Wort aber 3 Vokale, und 2 davon schreibt man mit dem Buchstaben »e«. Die fette Hervorhebung zeigt an, welcher dieser Vokale dem IPA-Symbol entspricht. Das zweite »e« in »lebendig« ist nämlich kein [e] sondern ein [ɛ], das noch dazu betont ist, und in meiner Liste daher als [ˈɛ] dargestellt wird.

Comment: @Hubert: OK. Aber als Niederländer spreche ich schon mal (nicht oft!) was falsch aus und wollte nur sicher gehen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ich wage den Versuch einer Antwort für Monophthonge, und beziehe mich ausschließlich auf Phoneme. Ich verwende den Begriff *Gespanntheit* für das Merkmal, das einen Vokal von seinem „relativ offenerem Partner“ unterscheidet (etwa /i/ zu /ɪ/).

Listen auf Wikipedia sind natürlich immer mit Vorsicht zu genießen, aber das liegt aber gerade bei diesem Thema daran, dass die Unterscheidung Phonem/Phon in der Praxis schwieriger ist als in der Theorie. Für Monophthonge finde ich [diese Liste](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache#Monophthonge) relativ akkurat; sie nimmt wohl die engstmögliche Interpretation an. Die [in der Frage verlinkte Liste](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokal#Vokale_im_Deutschen) dagegen beinhaltet meiner Meinung nach auch mehrere (mehr oder minder) freie Allophone (es ist ja dort auch nicht von *Phonemen* die Rede, sondern nur von *Vokalen*).

Die Unterscheidung *betonter/unbetonter* Vokal lasse ich aus, weil sie auf der Segmentebene nicht relevant ist (deshalb auch kein IPA-Zeichen dafür); Betonung an einer Position kann die Wahl eines Allophons beeinflussen, ist aber keine Eigenschaft eines isolierten Lautes.

Folgende Liste von 14–17 phonemischen vokalischen Monophthongen des Deutschen stammt aus [diesem Buch](https://www.amazon.de/Phonetik-Phonologie-Basiswissen-Therapie-Grassegger/dp/3824804832/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1487764001&sr=8-1&keywords=phonetik+phonologie) (Grassegger: *Phonetik/Phonologie*, S. 89); der Verfasser ist Professor für Phonetik (Sprachwissenschaftler, kein Germanist, und Österreicher). Die mit Stern markierten Einträge haben „Phonemstatus, [der] je nach Interpretation unterschiedlich bewertet wird“ (Original [hier](https://postimg.org/image/6rpqy8rhl)).

Phoneme werden üblicherweise mit Schrägstrichen notiert, um sie von Phonen zu unterscheiden. Zu jedem Eintrag gibt es zwei Minimalpaare: eines für irgendeinen Qualitätkontrast, und eines für den entsprechenden Quantitätskontrast. Letzterer ist relevant, weil die Vokale fast alle in Paaren mit einer kurzen, ungespannten und eine langen, gespannten Variante vorkommen, womit sich das (eigentlich suprasegmentale) Merkmal *Länge* in das Phonem hineinnehmen lässt (zur Diskussion siehe [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache#Vokalsystem); offenbar gibt es die Annahme eines Merkmals *Silbenschnitt*, das zugrunde liegt, aber ich bin kein Germanist und weiß nicht mehr darüber).

1. /iː/

   - liegen – lügen: /iː/ – /y/
   - Miete – Mitte: /iː/ – /ɪ/
2. /ɪ/

   - Mitte – Mette: /ɪ/ – /ɛ/
   - Kinn – Kien: /ɪ/ – /iː/
3. /yː/

   - lügen – legen: /yː/ – /eː/
   - fühlen – füllen: /yː/ – /ʏ/
4. /ʏ/

   - Hülle – Hölle: /ʏ/ – /œ/
   - Hütte – Hüte: /ʏ/ – /yː/
5. /eː/

   - leben – laben: /eː/ – /aː/
   - beten – betten: /eː/ – /ɛ/
6. /ɛ/

   - Welle – Wolle: /ɛ/ – /ɔ/
   - stellen – stehlen: /ɛ/ – /eː/
7. /ɛː/*

   - Bären – Beeren: /ɛː/ – /eː/
   - stählen – stellen: /ɛː/ – /ɛ/
8. /øː/

   - Bögen – Bogen: /øː/ – /oː/
   - Höhle – Hölle: /øː/ – /œ/
9. /œ/

   - Höcker – Hocker: /œ/ – /ɔ/
   - Höcker – Höker: /œ/ – /øː/
10. /aː/

    - Hase – Hose: /aː/ – /oː/
    - Staat – Stadt: /aː/ – /a/
11. /a/

    - Art – Ort: /a/ – /ɔ/
    - Schall – Schal: /a/ – /aː/
12. /oː/

    - oben – eben: /oː/ – /eː/
    - Ofen – offen: /oː/ – /ɔ/
13. /ɔ/

    - stocken – stecken: /ɔ/ – /ɛ/
    - Rotte – rote: /ɔ/ – /oː/
14. /uː/

    - Brut – Brot: /uː/ – /oː/
    - spuken – spucken: /uː/ – /ʊ/
15. /ʊ/

    - Lust – Last: /ʊ/ – /a/
    - Bulle – Buhle: /ʊ/ – /uː/
16. /ə/*

    - Lehre – Lehrer: /ə/ – /ɐ/
    - (G*e*bet – g*e*bet: /ə/ – /eː/)
17. /ɐ/*

    - Fischer – Fische: /ɐ/ – /ə/
    - (kein Quantitätskontrast)

Die Zweifel bestehen, glaube ich, deshalb, weil es nicht möglich ist, ein „Standarddeutsch“ ohne Rücksicht auf die Varietät zu behandeln.

Der Kontrast [eː] – [ɛː] ist schon in der Frage diskutiert worden; während ich *Säle* und *Seele* auch beide mit [eː] sprechen würde, nehme ich aber den grammatischen Unterschied von *lege* und *läge* (und *lecke*!) so stark wahr, dass ich davon ausgehe, dass man in meiner Varietät von unterschiedlichen Phonemen, also /eː/ und /ɛː/ ausgehen kann, selbst wenn sie in der Realisierung durch einen phonologischen Prozess zusammenfallen.

Die Schwas [ɐ] und [ə] würde ich für mich nicht als Phonem annehmen, da sie immer „nur“ Resultat eines phonologischen Prozesses sind und nicht mit anderen Phonemen kontrastieren. Das oben angeführte *Gebet – gebet*, die ich beide mit [e] aussprechen würde, führe ich auf die spezifische Variante der Schwächung des unbetonten [e] in *Gebet* in manchen Varietäten zurück. Hall (2000), ein Standardwerk zur Phonologie, sagt dazu (S. 70 f.):

> Obwohl das /ə/ nach Meinung der meisten Forscher zu den Phonemen des Deutschen zählt, hat dieser Laut einen besonderen Status, denn seine Verteilung ist in vielen Fällen vorhersagbar [, und] [ɐ] ist kein Phonem des Deutschen, sondern ein Allophon von /ʀ/.

Die Unterschied von [i]/[ɪ], [y]/[ʏ], etc. ist auch kein phonemischer Kontrast – [i] und [y] als kurzer Vokal kommen einfach als Variante des „langen“ Phonems in unbetonter Stellung vor (woraus man vielleicht schließen könnte, dass eben nicht die Länge, sondern die Gespanntheit oder der „Silbenschnitt“ das zugrundeliegende Merkmal sind).

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese hervorragende Antwort. Trotzdem Widerspruch zu: »*Vor allem ist [die Unterscheidung "betonter/unbetonter" Vokal] ziemlich redundant, da lange Laute nur in betonter Stellung vorkommen können.*« Gegenbeispiele: 1. Silbe kurz und betont, 2. Silbe **lang und unbetont**: »*Alltag*«, »*Vortrag*«, »*unschön*«, »*Balsam*«, »*Leichnam*«, »*Herzog*«, »*Kleinod*« usw. Oder vorne unbetont, hinten betont, beide lang: »Lebwohl«. Lange unbetonte Vokale findet man auch in: *wunder**bar**, Al**mo**sen, ein**sam**, Febru**ar**, Reich**tü**mer, Alko**hol*** usw.

Comment: Stimmt, das war unnötig spekuliert. Es sollte, denke ich, so sein, dass in betonter Stellung die Paarung Länge/Gespanntheit in der Realisierung immer erhalten bleibt (also das im letzten Absatz Genannte nicht eintritt), außer bei /a/ und /ɛ/, und ungespannte Vokale immer kurz sind.

Answer (score 3):

Meine Erfahrung vor allem beim Deutsch-Unterricht für Geflüchtete, speziell aus arabisch-sprechenden Ländern, sagt mir: 
Es gibt im Deutschen ***15 Vokal-Phoneme***. Deutsch - die Sprache mit 15 Vokalen!
Die Liste in der Answer 1 ist sehr gut, lediglich die Nummern 5/16. bzw. 2/17 fallen in der Praxis zusammen. 
Phoneme sind für mich Laute (Lautspektren mit vielleicht verschiedenen, aber doch sehr sehr ähnlich gesprochenen Phonen/Lautvarianten), die, wenn ich sie austausche, zu einem Bedeutungswechsel des Wortes führen, in dem sie vorkommen. Auch das zeigt die Liste in Answer 1 ganz hervorragend.