# Liste deutscher Minimalpaare

Tags: phonetics

**Welche Wort-Paare (und Wort-Gruppen) sind geeignet, die Unterschiedlichkeit von Laut-Paaren in der deutschen Sprache zu belegen?**

---

### Definition: Minimalpaar

Ein Minimalpaar ist ein Paar von zwei Wörtern mit unterschiedlicher Bedeutung, die sich nur in einem einzigen Laut unterscheiden, sonst aber genau gleich ausgesprochen werden. Das Paar

> **Stahl - Stall**
>   Aussprache: [**ʃtaːl**] - [**ʃtal**]

ist ein solches Minimalpaar.
(Zur Lautschrift siehe die beiden Wikipedia-Artikel  [Internationales Phonetisches Alphabet (IPA)](http://Internationales%20Phonetisches%20Alphabet) und [Liste der IPA-Zeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen).)

Dieses Paar ist ein Beleg dafür, dass das lange [aː] und das kurze [a] nicht einfach nur zwei mögliche Aussprachevarianten desselben Lauts sind (*fachsprachlich: zwei Allophone desselben Phonems*), sondern dass es sich hier um zwei unterschiedliche Vokale handelt (*die beiden Phone sind zwei verschiedene Phoneme*). Denn wenn man aus einem kurzen [a] ein langes macht, ohne sonst etwas im Wort zu verändern, entsteht (zumindest in diesem Fall) daraus ein neues Wort.

Manchmal kommt es auch vor, dass sich gleich mehrere Wörter in nur einem Laut unterscheiden, zum Beispiel:

> **Stiel - still - Stahl - Stall - Stuhl**
>   [**ʃtiːl**] - [**ʃtɪl**] - [**ʃtaːl**] - [**ʃtal**] - [**ʃtuːl**]

Ich weiß nicht, ob es dafür einen bereits etablierten Begriff gibt. Ich nenne diese Gruppen hier »Minimalgruppen«. Die hier dargestellte Gruppe hat fünf Elemente, woraus sich 10 Paare bilden lassen. Fände man ein sechstes Wort, das in diese Gruppe passen würde, hätte man bereits 15 Paare, mit einem siebenten Wort schon 21 Paare. Große Gruppen sind also besonders wertvoll, weil sie sich in viele Paare aufspalten lassen.

Der andere Fall liegt bei verschiedenen Lauten (*Phonen*) vor, die man beliebig austauschen kann, ohne dass sich die Bedeutung des Wortes ändert. So gibt es im Deutschen beispielsweise drei gleichwertige Arten, das Wort »rot« auszuspechen:

- [⁠roːt]
- [⁠ʀoːt]
- [⁠ʁoːt]

Bei dem (gesprochenen) Paar [⁠roːt] - [⁠ʀoːt] hört man zwar deutlich, dass der erste Vokal unterschiedlich ausgesprochen wird, aber beide Wörter werden als derselbe Begriff (nämlich als das Wort »rot«) verstanden. Somit ist [⁠roːt] - [⁠ʀoːt] kein Minimalpaar.

Weil es im Deutschen aber überhaupt kein Wort-Paar gibt, bei dem es einen Unterschied macht, ob ein darin enthaltenes R als [⁠r⁠], [⁠ʀ⁠] oder [⁠ʁ⁠] ausgesprochen wird, bezeichnet man im Deutschen die drei *Phone* [⁠r⁠], [⁠ʀ⁠] und [⁠ʁ⁠] als *Allophone* desselben *Phonems*. Man kennzeichnet ein Phonem dadurch, dass man es nicht zwischen eckige Klammern schreibt, sondern zwischen zwei Schrägstriche. Im Deutschen sind mit dem *Phomen* /r/ immer die drei *Phone* [⁠r⁠], [⁠ʀ⁠] und [⁠ʁ⁠] gemeint. (In anderen Sprachen können aber z.B. [⁠r⁠] und [⁠ʀ⁠] durchaus dazu führen, dass Wörter, die sich nur dadurch unterscheiden, dass man [⁠r⁠] gegen [⁠ʀ⁠] austauscht, unterschiedliche Bedeutung haben.)

(Damit wären nun auch die Begriffe »*Phon*«, »*Allophon*« und »*Phonem*« definiert.)

---

### Frage

Mich interessiert nun, welche Phone man in der gesprochenen deutschen Sprache zu Phonemen zusammenfassen kann, und welche unterscheidbaren Phonem-Paare man mit Hilfe von Minimalpaaren unterscheiden kann.

Mich interessiert vorrangig nur das Standarddeutsch, dies aber, falls das von Belang sein sollte, in allen drei Varietäten (deutsches, österreichisches und schweizerisches Standarddeutsch).

Ich grenze meine Frage also vorrangig auf jenes Deutsch ein, das gegenwärtig von ausgebildeten Berufs-Sprechern in Deutschland, Österreich und der Schweiz gesprochen wird (Fernseh- und Radiomoderatoren, Schauspieler, Synchronsprecher und ähnliche Berufe), unter Auslassung von Fremdwörtern die möglicherweise Vokale enthalten, die im Deutschen normalerweise nicht vorkommen.

Meine Frage bezieht sich auf:

- **einfache Vokale (Monophthonge)**
  Wie man aus dem oben gesagten bereits erkennen kann, bezieht sich meine Frage (unter anderem) auf einfache Vokale, also Monophthonge
- **Diphthonge (Zwielaute)**
  Ich suche auch nach Paaren, die zwischen Monophthongen und Diphthongen unterscheiden, z.B.:

  > **Stiel - steil**
  >    [**ʃtiːl**] - [**ʃtaɪ̯l**]

  (Weil »Stiel« bereits ein Element einer größeren Gruppe ist, gehört auch »steil« in dieselbe Gruppe)
  Ebenso suche ich nach Paaren, die verschiedene Diphthonge voneinander unterscheiden, z.B:

  > **Laus - Luis** (Vorname)
  >   [**laʊ̯s**] - [**lʊɪ̯s**]
- **betont - unbetont**
  Betonte Silben ziehen die Aufmerksamkeit auf sich, daher habe ich allen obigen Beispielen, betonte Vokale verwendet. Deutsch enthält aber auch Vokale, die nur in unbetonten Silben vorkommen. Ich suche auch nach Minimalpaaren in unbetonten Silben, z.B.

  > **jene - jener**
  >   [**ˈjeːnə**] - [**ˈjeːnɐ**]

  Ganz besonders würde mich interessieren, ob es auch Fälle gibt, wo allein der Wechsel zwischen betont und unbetont bei einem sonst gleichen Vokal einen Bedeutungsunterschied verursacht. (Dafür habe ich noch kein Beispiel gefunden)
- **Konsonanten**
  Ich suche aber auch nach Minimalpaaren, die Konsonanten voneinander unterscheiden, z.B.:

  > **Tatze - Katze**
  >   [**ˈtaʦə**] - [**ˈkaʦə**]

  ... aber auch nach Paaren, die Konsonanten von Vokalen unterscheiden können, wovon es vermutlich nicht all zu viele geben wird.

  > **Christkinder - Christkindl**
  >   [**ˈkʀɪstˌkɪndɐ**] - [**ˈkʀɪstˌkɪndl̩**]

Answer (score 3):

Dies ist eine Community-Wiki-Antwort. Das heißt, dass sie jeder editieren darf (und auch ausdrücklich aufgefordert ist das zu tun) um diese Antwort zu erweitern.

---

**betonte und unbetonte Vokale und Diphthonge**
Um betonte und unbetonte Vokale (und Diphthonge) unterscheiden zu können, werden betonte Vokale mit dem Zeichen »ˈ« vor dem Vokal gekennzeichnet. Unbetonte Vokale erkennt man daran, dass dieses Zeichen fehlt.

**kurze und lange Vokale**
Um kurze und lange Vokale unterscheiden zu können, werden lange Vokale mit dem Zeichen »ː« hinter dem Vokal gekennzeichnet. Kurze Vokale erkennt man daran, dass dieses Zeichen fehlt.

**Reihenfolge der Vokale**
Um der Ähnlichkeit der Klänge Rechnung zu tragen, und weil es wesentlich mehr Laute als Buchstaben gibt, wähle ich nicht die alphabetische Reihung, sondern diese Reihenfolge:

> [i ɪ e ə ɛ a ɐ o ɔ u ʊ y ʏ ø œ]

Innerhalb gleicher Vokale  reihe ich lange vor kurze und bei gleicher Länge betonte vor unbetonte. Das ergibt im Detail dann diese Ordnung:

> [ˈiː ˈi iː i ˈɪː ˈɪ ɪː ɪ ...]

Diphthonge ordne ich direkt hinter jenem Vokal ein, mit dem der Diphthong beginnt. Diphthonge mit gleichem ersten Vokal werden nach dem zweiten Vokal gereiht.

---

### Gruppen

- [ˈiː] - [ˈɪ] - [ˈɛː] - [ˈɛ] - [ˈaː] - [ˈa] - [ˈaɪ̯] - [ˈaʊ̯] - [ˈoː] - [ˈɔ] - [ˈɔɪ̯] - [ˈøː] - [ˈuː]
  riete - ritte - Räte - rette - Rate - Ratte - reite - Raute - rote - Rotte - reute - Röte - Route
- [ˈiː] - [ˈɪ] - [ˈeː] - [ˈɛ] - [ˈaː] - [ˈaɪ̯] - [ˈaʊ̯] - [ˈoː] - [ˈɔ] - [ˈuː] - [ˈʊ] - [ˈʏ]
  Beat - Bit - Beet - Bett - Bad - Byte - baut - Boot - Bot - buht - Butt - Bütt
- [ˈiː] - [ˈeː] - [ˈɛː] - [ˈɛ] - [ˈaː] - [ˈa] - [ˈaʊ̯] - [ˈoː] - [ˈɔ] - [ˈuː] - [ˈʊ] - [ˈøː] - [ˈyː]
  liegst - legst- lägst - leckst - lagst - lackst - laugst - logst - lockst - lugst - luchst - lögst - lügst
- [ˈiː] - [ˈɛ] - [ˈa]
  viel - Fell - Fall
- [ˈiː] - [ˈɪ] - [ˈɛː] - [ˈɛ] - [ˈaː] - [ˈa] - [ˈoː] - [ˈuː] - [ˈøː]
  wiegst - wichst - wägst - wächst - wagst - wachst - wogst - wuchst - wögst
- [ˈiː] - [ˈɪ] - [ˈaɪ̯] - [ˈaː] - [ˈa] - [ˈuː]
  Stiel - still - steil - Stahl - Stall - Stuhl
- [ˈiː] - [ˈeː] - [ˈoː] - [ˈuː] - [ˈyː]
  Tier - Teer - Tor - Tour - Tür
- [ˈiː] - [ˈeː] - [ˈaː] - [ˈoː]
  Wiege - Wege - Waage - Woge
- [ˈɪ] - [ˈeː] - [ˈa] - [ˈɔ]
  Wirt - Wert - Wart - Wort
- [ˈiː] - [ˈeː] - [ˈɛː] - [ˈaː] - [ˈoː]
  siegen - Segen - sägen - sagen - sogen
- [ˈɛ] - [ˈuː] - [ˈʊ]
  Bässe - Buße - Busse
- [ˈɛ] - [ˈoː] - [ˈɔ]
  pellen - Polen - Pollen
- [ˈeː] - [ˈɛ] - [ˈoː]
  Weg - weg - wog
- [ˈɪ] - [ˈʏ] - [ˈa]
  Kiste - Küste - Kaste
- [ˈɛ] - [ˈʊ] - [ˈaː]
  Berg - Burg - barg
- [ˈeː] - [ˈøː] - [ˈuː]
  Meere - Möhre - Mure
- [ˈeː] - [ˈaː] - [ˈoː] - [ˈøː]
  lesen - lasen - losen - lösen

### Paare

(nur Paare, die in keiner der obigen Gruppen vorkommen)

- [ˈɪ] - [ˈɛ]
  Stirn - Stern
- [ˈɪ] - [ˈʊ]
  Himmel - Hummel
- [ə] - [ɐ]
  jene - jener
- [ˈɛː] - [ˈɛ]
  Täler - Teller
- [ˈɛ] - [ˈɔ]
  lecker - locker
- [ˈa] - [ˈʊ]
  Band - Bund
- [ˈʊ] - [ˈʏ]
  Stuck - Stück
- [ˈeː] - [ˈɛː]
  Meer - Mär

### Sonderfälle

Wechsel der Betonung

- [ˈʊ] - [ʊ] und [ˈa] - [a] betont/unbetont
  umfahren [ˈʊmfaːʁən]: etwas so anfahren, dass es umfällt. *Robert fährt das Stoppschild um.*
  umfahren [ʊmˈfaːʁən]: um etwas herum fahren. *Robert umfährt das Stoppschild.*
- [o] - [ˈoː] und [ˈɛ]  - [ɐ] betont/unbetont mit Wechsel der Qualität der Endsilbe (Vollsilbe - Reduktionssilbe)
  modern [moˈdɛʁn]: wenn etwas in Mode ist. *Hüte sind wieder modern.*
  modern [ˈmoːdɐn]: verfaulen, verrotten. *Holz beginnt zu modern wenn es ständig nass wird.*

Comment: Die Betonungszeichen erfüllen keine Funktion.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Doch, tun sie. Siehe *»umfahren«* ([ˈʊmfaːʁən] - [ʊmˈfaːʁən])

Comment: Ich habe aus der Liste das Wort *»Bark«*, das neben *»barg«* stand wieder entfernt. Das Wort *»barg«* wird nur in solchen Gegenden gleich wie *»Bark«* ausgesprochen, in denen die [Auslautverhärtung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslautverhärtung) angewendet wird. Das ist aber nur in den nördlichen Gegenden Deutschlands der Fall. Dort wo ich wohne (Österreich) werden *»Bark«* = [baʁk] und *»barg«* = [baʁg] deutlich voneinander unterschieden, ebenso in der Schweiz und im Süden Deutschlands ( Bayern, Baden-Württemberg)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast mit dem Argument müsste man einige der Ketten kräftig lichten, wo sich lustig g, ch und ck als gleichlautend tummeln. Davon hatte ich abgesehen, da es für einige südliche Dialekte wohl gleichlautend ist. Wird die selbe Nachsicht nicht für die nördliche Mundart angewandt, ist der Titel irreführend und man müsste den Allgemeinheitsanspruch des Titels und dieses Wiki-Postings aufgeben und den Titel auf "österreichische Minimalpaare" oder Ähnliches ändern.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Bei Minimalpaaren geht es um die Opposition von Phonemen. Die Betonung ist dagegen ein suprasegmentales Merkmal (betrifft also z.B. Silben und Wörter).

Comment: Insbesondere wird bspw. Bark und barg auf auf wiktionary im Hochdeutschen explizit als Homophon gelistet. Vergleiche https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/barg und https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bark

Comment: @planetmaker: Ich stimme mit dir darüber überein, dass einige der Gruppen kräftig gelichtet werden sollten. Es gibt auch bei südlichen Aussprachevarianten keinen Grund hier großzügig zu sein.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Wenn zwei Phone zum selben Phoneme gehören, bedeutet das, dass ein Wechsel von einem Phon zum anderen (innerhalb desselben Phonems) unter keinen Umständen zu einer Änderung der Bedeutung führt. Die beiden Betonungsvarianten des Wortes *»umfahren«* belegen aber sehr eindrucksvoll, das der Wechsel der Betonung genau zu einer solchen Bedeutungsänderung führt. Aus genau diesem Grund gehören [ˈʊ] und [ʊ] zu unterschiedlichen Phonemen. (Ebenso [ˈa] und [a], nach weiteren Beispielen suche ich noch.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Betonung kann bedeutungsunterscheidend sein. Aber sie ist kein segmentales Merkmal und damit nicht Eigenschaft eines Phonems, sondern einer Silbe. Im Deutschen kann jeder Vokal (mit Ausnahme von Schwa) Teil einer betonten Silbe sein. Die Betonung steht also quer zu den Merkmalen der Vokalphoneme. Zur Betonung als suprasegmentales Merkmal siehe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics), zum Phoneminventar des Deutschen https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache#Vokalsystem. In solchen Inventaren wird nicht nach Betonung unterschieden.

Comment: Es ist zwar richtig, dass Silben betont (oder nicht betont) werden, weswegen in der Lautschrift das Betonungssymbol auf immer vor einer Silbe und nicht direkt vor dem Silbenkern steht, aber die Betonung einer Silbe manifestiert sich nicht an den Rändern der Silbe sondern in ihrem Kern, also immer in einem Vokal oder - Falls eine Silbe keine Vokale enthält - in einem vokalisierten Konsonanten, wobei vokalisierte Konsonanten (bzw. solche Silben) immer unbetont sind. Auch Reduktionssilben sind immer unbetont, und nur dort können die beiden Schwa-Laute ​[⁠ə⁠]​ (letzter Laut in *»jede«*) und ...

Comment: ... [ɐ] (letzter Laut in *»jeder«,* dieserLaut fehlt übrigens in dem von dir zitierten Wikipedia-Artikel) vorkommen, was einmal mehr unterstreicht, dass die Silbenbetonung ganz allein von den Vokalen, also von einzelnen Lauten abhängt.

Comment: Die Betonung manifestiert sich im Kontrast zweier Silben ("relative prominence"). Deshalb macht es keinen Sinn, bei einem einsilbigen Wort ein Betonungszeichen zu setzen. Eine Notation wie [ˈʊ] habe ich hier zum ersten Mal gesehen und wollte auf den Fehler hinweisen.

Comment: Aber jetzt bin ich noch neugierig: Wie erklärst du dir denn, dass in Beschreibungen des Inventars der Vokalphoneme des Deutschen die Betonung keine Rolle spielt? (Quellen: Oben verlinkter Wikipediaartikel; Randnr. 24 der Duden-Grammatik; Kap. 6.1.2 von Kohlers *Einführung in die Phonetik*; Kap. 5 von http://web.vu.lt/flf/d.sileikaite/files/2015/03/Sileikaite-Kaishauri_2015_Phonetik.pdf; und alle anderen, die ich kenne.)

Comment: Das erkläre ich mir dadurch, dass zwei Vokale gar nie betont sein können ([⁠ə⁠] und [ɐ]) und dass die Betonung bei den anderen Vokalen so gut wie nie zu einer Änderung der Bedeutung des Wortes führt. Aber die beiden Versionen von *umfahren* belegen ganz eindeutig, dass das in Ausnahmefällen doch genau so ist, und dass man die Betonung zumindest dann hinzunehmen muss, wenn man solche Ausnahmen untersuchen will. Ich glaube ganz einfach, dass man jenen seltenen Fällen, in denen die Betonung die Bedeutung beeinflusst, bisher zu wenig Beachtung geschenkt hat.