# Gibt es ein Minimalpaar für /ʏ/ und /ə/?

Tags: pronunciation, vowel

Der Titel sagt eigentlich alles.

Ich weiß, dass es diese beiden Listen gibt, die aber vielleicht nicht jedem bekannt sind.

[Liste deutscher Minimalpaare](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34784/liste-deutscher-minimalpaare), [Wie viele Vokale gibt es im Deutschen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34755/wie-viele-vokale-gibt-es-im-deutschen?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Die beiden Vokale wirken auf mich sehr ähnlich, warum werden diese dannn als unterschiedliche Phoneme angesehen?

Comment: Ich halte es für unwahrscheinlich, dass Du tatsächlich dies fragen willst. Hast du ein Beispiel dessen, wo du die zwei Vokalen verwescheln würdest? Gerne im üblichen Alphabet.

Comment: @c.p. Ich frage deshalb, weil ich vermute, dass ich in englischen Wörtern, bei denen <y> /ɪ/ ausgesprochen wird (symbol, olympics, crystal etc.), ein /ʏ/ benutze, was aber auch einfach ein /ə/ sein könnte. Und das /ʏ/ [hier](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/) klingt für mich nicht nach einem kurzen ü, sondern nach einem langen ö.

Comment: @corvus_192: [ʏ] kommt in anderen Sprachen durchaus auch als langer Vokal vor (in der Lautschrift: [ʏː]), und klingt dann wie auf der von dir verlinkten Seite. Aber in deutschen Wörtern ist [ʏ] immer kurz. Wenn im Deutschen ein langes ü zu sprechen ist (»kühl«, »Bühne«) dann wird stattdessen der Laut [y:] (gerundeter geschlossener Vorderzungenvokal) verwendet, der eng mit dem [i:] verwandt ist: Sage »die« mit sehr langem i und forme die Lippen zu einer kleinen runden Öffnung, die du sonst bei u (wie in »du«) machst, jedoch ohne die Position der Zunge im Mund zu verändern, und du erhältst [y:].

Comment: (Fortsetzung): Auf dieselbe Weise kann man [ʏ] produzieren: Sage ein wort mit kurzen i, z.B. »Kiste« [ˈkɪstə] und forme wieder die Lippen zu der für u typischen kleinen runden Öffnung, und schon wird daraus »Küste« [ˈkʏstə].
Übrigens: Die beiden Vokale in »Küste« sind genau die Laute, die du schwer unterscheiden kannst. Du kannst dir das Wort hier anhören: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Küste

Comment: @corvus_192 Da vergleilchst du englische mit deutscher Phonetik. Ich fragte nach zwei deutschen Wörtern, deren Phonetik zu verwechseln wäre. Soweit ich weiß *ü* und *y* liest man nie /ə/.

Comment: @c.p. nach der ausführlichen Antwort ist mir auch klar, dass es ein solches Minimalpaar nicht gibt. Ich höre auch einen Unterscheid zwischen den Vokalen in "Küste", aber ich dachte mir, dass es vielleicht ganz hilfreich sein könnte, rauszufinden, welchen Laut ich bei den englischen Wörtern benutze.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ich halte es für sehr unwahrscheinlich, ein solches Minimalpaar zu finden, weil diese Laute die Kerne von sehr unterschiedlichen Silbenarten sind.

---

### [ʏ]

Der Laut [ʏ] (gerundeter zentralisierter fast geschlossener Vorderzungenvokal) ist das kurze ü in deutschen Wörtern und kommt betont z.B. in folgenden Wörtern vor:

> h**ü**bsch
>   H**ü**ndin
>   M**ü**cke

Unbetont findet man [ʏ] unter anderem in

> Abk**ü**rzung
>   urspr**ü**nglich
>   Grundst**ü**ck

Silben, in denen in deutschen Wörtern [ʏ] vorkommt, sind niemals Reduktionssilben, und der Laut wird immer mit den Buchstaben »ü« oder »y« (»typisch«, »System«) geschrieben.

---

### [ə]

Der Schwa-Laut [ə] (mittlerer Zentralvokal) hingegen kommt im Deutschen ausschließlich in Reduktionssilben vor, und wird immer mit dem Buchstaben »e« geschrieben. Beispiele sind:

> Tort**e**
>   ein**e**m
>   dies**e**s
>   *(während du)* spielt**e**st
>   Hag**e**l
>   b**e**halten

---

### Reduktionssilben

Eine Reduktionssilbe liegt dann vor, wenn die Silbe dermaßen schwach betont wird, dass ...

- ... entweder gar kein Vokal mehr klingt (re**den** = [ˈʀeː**dn̩**]),
- ... oder der Vokal, der den Kern der Silbe ausmacht, nur kurz und schwach gemurmelt wird.

Als Vokale in Reduktionssilben werden im Deutschen nur das Schwa ([ə], siehe oben) und das Tiefschwa ([ɐ]; fast offener Zentralvokal) verwendet, das immer mit den beiden Buchstaben »er« geschrieben wird.

Das Tiefschwa findet man z.B. in diesem Wörtern:

- Lehr**er**
- hund**er**t
- *(du)* weig**er**st *(dich)*

Die beiden Laute [ə] und [ɐ] findet man im Deutschen ausschließlich in Reduktionssilben, und Reduktionssilben können im Deutschen auch nur diese beiden Vokale oder einen vokalisierten Konsonanten als Silbenkern enthalten.

Wenn es ein [ʏ]/[ə]-Minimalpaar gäbe, müsste die Silbe, in welcher der entsprechende Laut enthalten ist, in einem Fall eine Vollsilbe sein, und im anderen eine Reduktionssilbe. Ich glaube nicht, dass es solche Paare geben kann.

(Nur als Ergänzung: Es gibt [ə]/[ɐ]-Minimalpaare, z.B. »jen*e* - jen*er*«)

Comment: Ich glaube auch nicht, dass es ein solches Paar gibt, aber ich mache mal einen Versuch: Steckender/steckendürr. Aber auch dieses etwas mühsam konstruierte Paar funktioniert nur bei nachlässiger Aussprache, da "dürr" normalerweise ein deutlich hörbares r am Ende hat.

Comment: Das «Tiefschwa» ist selbstverständlich nichts weiter als eine Aussprachemöglichkeit von Schwa + /r/.

Comment: Ich bin heute zufällig auf eines gestoßen, wenn auch etwas weit hergeholt: Apfelanlage/Abfüllanlage.

Comment: @corvus_192: Leider nein. In der zweiten Silbe von *»Apfel«* bildet ein vokalisierter Konsonant (nämlich ein vokalisiertes L, das in der Lautschrift durch ein kleines L mit einem kurzen senkrechten Strich darunter dargestellt wird: »l̩« ) den Silbenkern: [ˈʔapfl̩] (Erste Silbe: [ʔa] zweite: [pfl̩]). Der Laut [ə], um den es hier eigentlich geht, kommt im Wort *»Apfel«* gar nicht vor.